# Grouping Tubule data and showing all matching values in one column

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have data in the following structure and my goal is to group the data by the columns Region, Manager, and Employee Name then to show all the products IDs sold by these group. The data is in the following format where product ID sold is the unique key value.

| Region | Manager | Employee Name | Product ID Sold |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mid Atlantic | Jim | Name 1 | 11112 |  |
| North East | Bob | Name 2 | 21323 |  |
| Mid Atlantic | Cat | Name 3 | 43124 |  |
| Mid Atlantic | Cat | Name 4 | 123421 |  |
| North East | Bob | Name 5 | 3245 |  |
| North West | Kate | Name 6 | 12343124 |  |
| North West | Mike | Name 7 | 1234324 |  |
| North West | Mike | Name 8 | 3234 |  |
| North West | Kate | Name 9 | 53125 |  |
| Mid Atlantic | Jim | Name 1 | 2133 |  |
| North East | Bob | Name 2 | 123123 |  |
| Mid Atlantic | Cat | Name 3 | 123213 |  |
| Mid Atlantic | Cat | Name 4 | 213123 |  |
| North East | Bob | Name 5 | 123213 |  |
| North West | Kate | Name 6 | 123123 |  |
| North West | Mike | Name 7 | 123123 |  |
| North West | Mike | Name 8 | 123123 |  |
| North West | Kate | Name 9 | 123213 |  |

Goal Structure

| Region | Manager | Employee Name | Product ID Sold |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mid Atlantic | Jim | Name 1 | 11112 | 2133 | 213213 | 1232 | 1123 |
|  | Cat | Name 3 | 43124 | 123213 |  |  |  |
|  |  | Name 4 | 123421 | 213123 |  |  |  |
| North East | Bob | Name 2 | 21323 | 123123 |  |  |  |
|  |  | Name 5 | … | … |  |  |  |
| North West | Kate | Name 6 | … | … | … | … |  |
|  |  | Name 9 | … | … |  |  |  |
|  | Mike | Name 7 | … | … |  |  |  |
|  |  | Name 8 | … | … |  |  |  |